# Azure maps Fuzzy search: when I search on azure maps I want postal codes to be autocompleted

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-maps

I am creating an autocomplete widget using jQuery and ajax, and some queries will be in the form of zip codes. When the user types in less than 5 digits of their postal code, I want azure maps to return a fuzzy search like they would if I types in a partial city name. '5393' should return results with the various Wisconsin cities under those numbers even though it is incomplete.
here is my current key:
[https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key={key}&api-version=1.0&query={query}&typeahead=True&countrySet=US&view=Auto&entityType=PostalCodeArea&limit=20](https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=%7Bkey%7D&api-version=1.0&query=%7Bquery%7D&typeahead=True&countrySet=US&view=Auto&entityType=PostalCodeArea&limit=20)

I have already looked through the documentation extensively, so if you could point my to a parameter or something else I can do to have this happen I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try using the address service rather than the fuzzy search service. The fuzzy search service favors addresses and full addresses. With the address service you can limit the result entity type. Try adding `&entityType=PostalCodeArea`. If this doesn't work, try using the V2 search geocoding service, that is a lot more flexible by the looks of things.

Comment: So I recently got the entityType param to work for my solution, however as of 2 or so days ago, without changing anything about my url, azure maps no longer returns any results with a PostalCodeArea entity type with a string search. I find this extremely odd as nothing about my code has changed except for a new key from a swap, do you know of why this might be?

Comment: I recommend contacting the Azure support team since this would be a production impacting change. I'm not on the maps team at Microsoft, I just have a lot of experience using it.

Comment: @landenHawley did you figure out a solution for this?